# Second polygon will not appear in graphics

Tags: java, polygon, paint

I'm having trouble with polygons, these are supposed to be stars im creating, I want to create a starry night sky so i took to drawing each one out individually. The first one turned out good but the second doesnt show up at all on my picture. My prof said not to design it in a graphics program and gave us a special program that will tell us the correct x and y coordinates to make the stars. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 public void paintComponent(Graphics page)
          {
     page.setColor(Color.yellow);
       int[] x  = {42,52,72,52,60,40,15,28,9,32,42};
       int [] y = {38,62,68,80,105,85,102,75,58,60,38};
       page.fillPolygon(x, y, 11);

       page.setColor(Color.yellow);
       int[] x1 = {358,341,359,363,377,365,373,355,336,342,320,340};
       int[] y1 = {35,55,36,53,57,65,74,67,75,65,58,56};
       page.fillPolygon(x, y, 11);
```

Comment: You are using `x,y` instead of `x1,y1`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic is quite right. You are drawing the same thing twice. Also your second set of arrays have 12 values in so you need page.fillPolygon(x1, y1, 12)

Comment: Ok, that makes sense it works now thank you!

Comment: Also, I wanted a plane i drew to be able to fly over said stars and the plane appear in front of them when going over them, would i having to do anything differently to the code?